# How to sum values in a column based on values in a different column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, lets say I have

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |

then i would want sql to return

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |
| 2 | 11 |

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic sql.

```
select id, sum(values) as values
from foo
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Select ID,sum(values)
From table
Group by ID;